# Traceroute (tracert) anycast address on Windows strange behavior

Tags: networking, anycast

```
Tracing route to d.resolvers.level3.net [4.2.2.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    25 ms    27 ms    26 ms  d.resolvers.level3.net [4.2.2.4]

Trace complete.


Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    37 ms    40 ms    43 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```

Obviously there must be more than 1 hop because I am in private network.  What's wrong with tracert? It does not support anycast?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a network device between you and those nodes that's confusing matters.  Maybe it's artificially upping the TTL on your sent packets, or trying to play proxy in some strange way.

What does the network topology look like - and are you certain that this only occurs when you trace to one of those public DNS resolvers?